# Добавить обработчик жеста к стороннему view без перекрытия встроенных жестов

Tags: android, изображения, touch, gestures

Во fragment на весь экран используется ImageScaleView с обработкой нажатий и жестов. Как к нему добавить свой обработчик жеста не перекрывая его встроенных функций?

При добавлении своего обработчика весь функционал ImageScaleView перестает работать.

```html
        imageScaleView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getContext()) {
            public void onSwipeUp() {
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`View` имеет встроенного обработчика касаний - `onTouchEvent()`, если вы его "перекрываете", то это как бы ваша личная трагедия :)

Ну если серьезно по уму надо делать вызывать встроенный обработчик типа:

```
  imageScaleView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
           result = v.onTouchEvent(me); //вызываем встроенный обработчик
           //что-то свое
           // blah-blah
           return result; //возвращаем результат работы встроенного обработчика
        }
    });
```